# Set a scheduled task for logoff/shutdown to run a script

Tags: windows-10, script, scheduled-tasks

We have a script that we would like to run at logoff (preferably shutdown). I am already aware of the LGPO option to run a script at shutdown, but we would like the control of Task Scheduler to run this.

What event ID(s) do I need to enter for this to happen?

Reason we want task scheduler is if the script runs for more than x minutes, we would stop the task, and reboot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write an answer, but have you looked in to adding "schtasks /Run " to a GPO logout/shutdown script, and configuring the task elsewhere?

Comment: That is a unique idea, one I haven't thought of. Testing Time!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the script ? And btw have you come across a auto login script ?

Comment: script is proprietary. And what do you mean by auto login? I know how to prevent auto login via scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've made a work around with shutdown scripts and are piggybacking off of the logoff ID's as well.